# PowerPoint VBA addin (ppam) fails to load for all users

Tags: installation, vba, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, windows-installer

I have a PowerPoint VBA addin (ppam file) which is packaged in an MSI installer for installation for all users of a machine. Following installation, a user gets some additional buttons in the PowerPoint ribbon to run the addin functions.

Unfortunately, some users - on machines within organisations such as schools - do not get these buttons in the ribbon and the addin appears not to be loaded although the MSI installer runs without complaint.

**How the addin is being installed**

The MSI installer is run (requiring administrator privileges). The addin goes into its own folder in "C:\Program Files (x86)".

The addin is enabled in the registry in the HKLM hive: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office[POWERPOINT_VERSION_NUM]\PowerPoint\AddIns\NameOfAddin". [POWERPOINT_VERSION_NUM] is replaced with the current version, for example "16.0" (This comes from "PowerPoint.Application\CurVer" in HKCR appended with ".0") - with autoload set to 1 and path set to the path of the ppam addin file in the Program Files directory.

Both the addin and the installer are signed with an EV code signing certificate.

**On the machines where this is failing:**

- The installer runs and the installation appears in the apps and features list and can be uninstalled.
- The add-in appears in the program files directory.
- Using an alternative installer - created with inno setup script, which installs for the current user only, modifies HKCU entries and puts the addin in "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns" results in the addin loading without problem when PowerPoint opens.
- Addins are NOT disabled in Trust Center Settings -> Addins

**UPDATED 6 February 2021:**

**Earlier theory - ruled out - group policy setting**

I've been able to disable all VBA addins in the group policy editor - and this is consistent with not seeing VBA addins marked as being disabled in the Trust Center Settings, however, setting this policy also disables per-user addins - which I am not seeing.

**Reproducing the issue**

The fact that the add-in seemed to be only failing on institutional devices led me in the wrong direction for this problem. The same issue was happening on someone's laptop with no exotic security settings - which led me to try installing the add-in with 64-bit Office instead of 32-bit Office: and this reproduces the issue exactly.

Comment: It may be that PPT/Office is set to disable unsigned add-ins. That's one thing that might explain what you're seeing.  Check File | Options | Trust Center, click the Trust Center Settings button and on the Add-ins pane, remove all checkmarks as a test. Then on the Macros pane, choose Disable all add-ins with notification.

Comment: This looks like it may well be the solution. In the add-ins pane, having the first two checked, or the third one checked (disable all application add-ins) reproduces the effect.

Comment: I am now signing both the add-ins themselves and the installers using an EV code signing certificate. Some people are still having this problem - and I still can't reproduce it. Could it be due to a group policy setting?

Comment: I gather that GP settings can override settings that individual users have chosen, so I imagine that might be the problem. Another oddball possibility: there are some apps that modify VBA code in PPTMs or PPAMs, etc. These may, depending on settings, invalidate the signature in the code. If you're not post-processing your add-in in any way, this wouldn't apply, of course.

Comment: Our code is not modifying itself in any way.

Comment: I've spoken to the people who are having this problem with computers on their network and it doesn't look like it's to do with a GP setting. Not sure where to look next.

Comment: "Our code is not modifying itself in any way."  I'm not referring to self-modifying code but to programs that modify add-ins (eg to provide protection against copying the code).

Answer (score 1):

The solution just involved some simple modifications to the installer (written using WIX - Windows Installer XML, and using the WIX tool set in Visual Studio).

The installer was being compiled as 32bit - which means that the add-in gets registered under the WOW6432Node in the registry - which is the right place for 32-bit Office and the wrong place for 64-bit Office. So the solution is to compile the installer project as x64, so that the add-in now gets registered in the right part of the registry for 64-bit Office.

Add a RegistryKey element to put the same information onto the WOW6432Node so that the add-in also works on 32-bit installs of Office (it's not possible to do this the other way around - compiling to 32-bit and adding a key on the non-WOW6432Node in HKLM\SOFTWARE).

Set the install directory to "ProgramFiles64Folder" (a built-in constant in WIX) - so the add-in always gets placed in the "Program Files" rather than "Program Files (x86)" directory.